# Returning Json Format response from c#

Tags: c#, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

I need following json response from ajax call:

```
[{url:"http://localhost:63220/Images/heroAccent.png"},
{url:"http://localhost:63220/Images/heroAccent.png"}]
```

**My ajax call is:**

```
function loadtest() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Home/TestMethod',
        async: true,
        dataType:'json',
        cache: false,
        error: function () {
            alert('Errror');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**My controller is:**

```
public JsonResult TestMethod()
    {
        var items = new[] {
                            new {url = "http://localhost:63220/Images/heroAccent.png"}, 
                            new {url = "http://localhost:63220/Images/heroAccent.png"} };

        return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

It gives the **response:**

```
    [{"url":"http://localhost:63220/Images/heroAccent.png"},
    {"url":"http://localhost:63220/Images/heroAccent.png"}]
```

But I need following response. How can I get it?

```
[{url:"http://localhost:63220/Images/heroAccent.png"},
{url:"http://localhost:63220/Images/heroAccent.png"}]
```

Comment: Why does it matter? Besides double quotes around the property is valid JSON. Your c# application should only accept valid JSON anyways.

Comment: You asked for invalid json format

Comment: Why you need this? That's the way how MVC serialize objects to JSON. Anyway you can map response on client side as you want...

Comment: I am using Simple image upload plugin from ckeditor. It needs this kind of ajax response.

Comment: `var data =[{"url":"http://localhost:63220/Images/heroAccent.png"},
    {"url":"http://localhost:63220/Images/heroAccent.png"}];

 console.log(eval(data));`

Comment: I am not allowed to edit anything from jquery. I can just call controller. So, I think I need help in c#. (http://ckeditor.com/addon/simple-image-browser)

Answer (score 1):

You get the response you need in a JSON format. To convert it to an object, use :

```
JSON.parse(data);
```

Answer (score -1):

**You can use class.**

```
 var items = new List<Item>() { new Item() { url = "http://www.google.com" }, new Item() { url = "http://www.youtube.com" } };
 return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

**Class**

```
 public class Item
    {
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: I don't see how this answer related to the question.